# (PDF.js) how to add Hand tool to your pdf page

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf.js

If I have some pdf page preview like in this example, how I can add it just hand tool, without adding all toolbar?

[jsfiddle pdfjs example](https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=wagvs9Lf)

```
pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

    // Wait for rendering to finish
    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
      pageRendering = false;
      if (pageNumPending !== null) {
        // New page rendering is pending
        renderPage(pageNumPending);
        pageNumPending = null;
      }
    });
  });
```